# Is this problem statement good for a GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, combinatorics

I am used to using GPU hardware for large scale matrix operations and vectorizing mathematical operations on a continuous space which has been discretized for numerical computation, but this is a completely different problem and I would like to know if it is suitable for a GPU.

Suppose I have a string `X` of length `N` and a string `Y` of length `M`, such that `N < M`. I can use, for example, the Python statement `if( X in Y )` to find if `X` is a substring of `Y`. Now, suppose that I have a string `X` and 10 million strings `{Y_i}`. Is it possible (worth it) to put this type of problem on a GPU? Rather than having this be 10 million operations, we could do it in one operation on a GPU, right?

The reason I am asking is that, in reality, I have maybe 10 Billion strings `{X_i}` and need to, for each string, compare it to every string in `{Y_i}` and am wondering if I can make it so that finding `X` in any of `{Y_i}` will be a GPU kernel for when these sets get incredibly large.

Comment: Do you always need to check whether $X \subset Y_i$ for _all_ $i$-s or do you just need to find a few strings $Y_j$ such that $X \subset Y_j$? In the latter case you would get the most speedup by ordering the sets $Y_i$ properly rather than parallelizing.